# Rewrite https://domain/subdir//foo to https:/domain/subdir/foo

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I'm trying to proxy a location with Nginx. 
Unforunately [the application is broken](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/issues/624) and will sometimes create a URL like `https://domain.com/subdir//foo` instead of `https://domain.com/subdir/foo`. (Note the extra slash.)

I'm using this location in my Nginx config file.

```
location /subdir/ {
    proxy_pass 0.0.0.0:8081/subdir/;
}
```

I've tried several different rewrites and locations to get the URL with the doubleslash to point to the one without.

Any insight on how to make this happen?

Comment: If anyone happens upon this question, I ended up just switching to Nginx

Answer (score 0):

The `$uri` variable contains a normalised URI with things like `//` replaced by a single `/`.

You may have success with:

```
location /subdir/ {
    rewrite ^ $uri break;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no dice.

Comment: Hmm. It works for me, but I did need to add the `http://` into the `proxy_pass` to remove a warning.

Comment: That was an over sight when I copy pasted. I'm wondering if it's because I'm proxying to a subdir...